# java.lang.unsatisfiedLinkError caused by the package name

Tags: java, java-native-interface, package

My program works well, if I just put it in the default package. Once I put it in a specific package it does not work. I get the following error messag:

```
Error Message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.**UnsatisfiedLinkError**: 
mypackage.my_java_class_name.nativeUpload(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

- OS: Ubuntu 12.04 32bits
- Java version: openjdk 7

Compiling:

```
javac mypackage/my.java
javah -jni mypackage.my_java_class_name
gcc -shared -fpic -o mylib.so -I/Path_of_jdk/Include -I/Path_of_jkd/Include/linux my.c
```

Running:

```
java -Dava.library.path=/path_of_myprogram/
```

Comment: Provide a short piece of code to replicate your problem. Also, make sure to specify the name of the package in your class by using `package the.package.im.using; /* rest of code */`

Answer (score 0):

Let me expand a bit on the comment by *[Luiggi Mendoza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065197/luiggi-mendoza)*.

Java is not interested in the **.h** file generated by the **javah** command. It looks for a C function called **Java_mypackage_my_1java_1class_1name_nativeUpload** in the **my.c** file. (note `_1` which are result of "translation" of `_` in the name of your class).

You cannot resolve this naming issue with **javah** alone.